# FlexPage Viewer error converting document, make sure the conversion tool is installed

Tags: flexpaper

I have deployed the FlexPaper.war  from http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

When I am clicking on document which I have uploaded I am getting the below message:

> error converting document, make sure the conversion tool is installed and that correct user permissions are applied to the SWF Path directory
> Click http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_php.jsp'>here for more information on configuring FlexPaper with JSP

Can you please tell me what the exact reason for the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that it means the SWFTools:

http://www.swftools.org/

I think it uses it to convert files to SWF or sth...